# How is x = &(*variable) different from x = variable?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've been trying to understand c++ by going over some projects and i came across this:

```
vector<Circle>::iterator circleIt = mCircles.end();
..
mCurrentDragCircle = &(*circleIt);
```

Why would you dereference and then reference it again?

Comment: For one, it will fail to compile if the target is not a pointer and there is no overload of the `*` dereference operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `*`-operator is overloaded for the `iterator` class. It doesn't do a simple dereference. Instead, it returns a reference to the variable it's currently pointing at. Using the reference operator on this returns a pointer towards the variable.

Using `mCurrentDragCircle = circleIt;` would assign the iterator to your field.

Comment: Such quick answers! thanks guys!
I was getting confused because `circleIt->param.method()..` was used earlier, but of course x= iterator would just assign the actual iterator!

Answer (score 5):

`circleIt` is an iterator, and iterators overload `operator*` so that they look like pointers. Dereferencing an iterator gives a reference to the value; `&` turns that into a pointer to the value. So this is converting an iterator to a pointer.

Btw., dereferencing past-the-end, i.e. `*v.end()`, has undefined behavior. The proper way to do this is

```
v.data() + v.size()
```

in C++11, or

```
&v[0] + v.size()
```

in C++98. Both assume the vector is non-empty.

Comment: The code had `if( circleIt != mCircles.end() ) {..`, I just omitted all the inbetween code. Is there a better way to indicate this rather then ".."?

Comment: @Daloupe: maybe `// manipulate circleIt so that's not end()`?

Answer (score 4):

Because of how iterators works.

```
*circleIt
```

will return instance of Circle, e.g. you can do

```
Circle & c = *circleIt;
```

Than you take address of that circle and store it into a pointer

```
Circle * mCurrentDragCircle  = & (*circleIt);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`&*` is a particularly pernicious idiom for extracting an underlying pointer. It's frequently used on objects that have an overloaded dereference operator `*`.

One such class of objects are iterators. The author of your class is attempting to get the address of the underlying datum for some reason. (Two pitfalls here, (i) `*end()` gives *undefined behaviour* and (ii) it appears that the author is storing the pointer value; blissfully unaware that modifications on that container could invalidate that value).

You can also see it used with smart pointers to circumvent reference counting.

My advice: avoid if at all possible.